# How to write unit tests using httptest with handlers using context in their definitions?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I've been trying for sometime to figure out how a write unit tests for handlers that use context as part of their definition.

Example

`func Handler(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`

After some googling I came accross this [article](https://elithrar.github.io/article/testing-http-handlers-go/) which made it seem as simple as

```
//copied right from the article

rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
// e.g. func GetUsersHandler(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
handler := http.HandlerFunc(GetUsersHandler)
```

When trying to to implement the tests like this I was given the error

```
cannot convert Handler (type func("context".Context, http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) to type http.HandlerFunc
```

So I drove into the definition of `HandleFunc` and found

```
// The HandlerFunc type is an adapter to allow the use of
// ordinary functions as HTTP handlers. If f is a function
// with the appropriate signature, HandlerFunc(f) is a
// Handler that calls f.
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)

// ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).
func (f HandlerFunc) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request) {
    f(w, r)
}
```

So the error makes sense... but now I'm at a lose because I need to test this Handler and it doesn't seem like I can using `httptest` as the article suggested.

Is there anyway to test my handlers with the `httptest` package?  If not how should I go about testing?

I'm using Go1.9

**UPDATE**

```
//Just so its clear this is what I'm currently trying to do

data := url.Values{}
data.Set("event_type", "click")
data.Set("id", "1")
data.Set("email", "")

req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "/", bytes.NewBufferString(data.Encode()))
Expect(err).To(BeNil())

rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
// this is the problem line. 
// The definition of Handler isn't (w ResponseWriter, r *Request)
// So I can't create a handler to serve my mock requests
handler := http.HandlerFunc(Handler)

handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
```

Comment: Why pass the handler as another parameter when `http.Request` already supports contexts?

Comment: This is legacy code before Go1.7 the entire app was built this way. I'm just adding new routes. Still the article made it seem like this was something that could be done and was done as an example.  Not sure how valid the article is now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httptest` includes everything you need to create a fake [Request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewRequest) and [ResponseWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#ResponseRecorder) for testing purposes, you just need to create an appropriate fake `Context` (whatever that means in your situation) and then pass all 3 to your handler function and validate what it writes to the ResponseWriter:

```
ctx := MakeMyContext()
w := httptest.NewRecorder()
r := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/myroute", nil)
// headers etc
MyHandler(ctx,w,r)
// Validate status, body, headers, whatever in r
```

Comment: Cool, I think still will work, give me a sec to verify